# HTML - PHP - Trying to inert a variable in <a href=>

Tags: php, html, echo

I am getting a variable from a SQL db - and wanting to add it to an HTML <a href=> tag.

While the variable is there - the echo statement doesn't like the PHP i have inserted and always bombs!

```
<?php
$field = "Folder2";
if ($field == $field){
        echo('<a href="/folder1/<?php echo $field ?>">123</a><br>
            ');
    }
?>
```

This always just returns - https://website.com/folder1/%3C?php%20echo%20$field%20?%3E

Which is : https://website.com/folder1/

I am new to this so it is bound to be just a typo or an apostrophe - but any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

are you trying in code `<?php` to open another `<?php`
You just need to use concatenation. use

```
<?php
    $field = "Folder2";
    if ($field == $field){
        echo '<a href="/folder1/'.$field.'">123</a><br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - worked great! First time too!! Can't upvote you as I am still a junior member - Grrr!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print <?php tags inside PHP

Try this

```
<?php
$field = "Folder2";
if ($field == $field){
echo "<a href=\"/folder1/$field\">123</a><br>";
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$field = "Folder2";
if ($field == $field){
?>
<a href="/folder1/<?php echo $field; ?>">123</a><br>
<?php
}
?>
```